# Where to find design patterns, best practices for Eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Our team is developing a Eclipse based IDE (typically a plugins), currently we are progressing good but I feel somehow we are feeling smell of bad practices in code. Example I can give here is, `eventListeners` :

Consider we have button named `button1` and in the same java file (just below the button) we are adding selection listener to it like:

```
button1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
    //Remaining code here
}
```

Which I feel is completly bad idea, and my question, is there any design pattern, best practices etc available for eclipse plugin development? Or do you have any small tips/suggestions for the same? I know there are books available like `Code Complete 2` etc etc, but I need bit suggestions respect to eclipse plugin development.

I tried in Google and didn't get much good informations regarding same, I got this IBM's [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-plugin-guide/section2.html). But I feel it's not very useful, any suggestions or tip is appreciated.

**Note:** Please let me know if it is not appropriate here or is it good for anyother stackexchange networks (like programmers), I can move it there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After several years of plugin development, I find these resources to be most useful for me when I find myself struggling on how to implement new feature:

1. **Eclipse sources**. Nothing will beat this. Try to find some already existing analogic part of what you're just doing and look how Eclipse developers did it - what patterns and extensions they used and so on. Helps to keep you plugins consistent with other parts of Eclipse. Eclipse Plugin Spy is your friend here (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>).
2. [**Platform Plug-in Developer Guide**](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=/2) - will guide you through basic concepts of Eclipse, like how to create menus properly, implement an editor, or save user preferences.
3. [**Eclipse Plug-ins (4th Edition)**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774159) - Well known must-have for plugins developer.

And, of course, Stack overflow :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I will wait for few answers, else I will accept yours.

Comment: +1 for the Eclipse plug-ins book.  It took me a month to get through the 2nd edition a few years ago and it was invaluable in understanding the Eclipse 3 architecture.

Comment: This is a great answer.  No need to wait for more. This is exactly what I would have said. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I like to add some more resources that I have found useful to dreo's answer. The eclipse sources are invaluable, if you want to understand something in detail. To understand global concepts however, I suggest to read as much tutorials as you can. I can recommend the following websites:

**[Eclipse Corner Articles](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/)** Has a lot of tutorials ranging from basic concepts to plugins specific topics.

**[Vogella Eclipse Tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html)** Also a good tutorial website. It deals with a lot of topics that are important for Eclipse RCP development.

**[SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)** More than 100 code snippets. Really useful, if you want to learn more about SWT and its capabilities.

**[The Official Eclipse FAQs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs)** Last but not least, I can recommend the official Eclipse FAQs. They provide compact solutions for a variety of topics.